# equalsIgnoreCase returns false even when strings are same in java

Tags: java, string, swing

```
int locctr = 0,toknum = 0;

    String temp;
    String d;
    String [] tok = new String[500];
    String[] lines = CODE.getText().split("\n");
    try
    {
        for(int i=0;i<lines.length;i++)
        {
            temp = lines[i];
            if(temp != null)
            {
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(lines[i],":,\t[]",true); 
                while (st.hasMoreTokens())
        {
                    String ss=st.nextToken();
                    tok[toknum] = ss;  
                    toknum++; //increment
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print("tok[0] is "+tok[0]);
        boolean r = tok[0].equalsIgnoreCase(".DATA");
        System.out.print("r is : "+r);
        if(r == true)
        {
           System.out.print("\n      INSIDE .DATA"); 
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
```

// input should be accepted for CODE ...its been accepted using a .txt file
CODE contains

```
.DATA
 DATAENDS
```

this code should be executed on button click......

PROBLEM : even when the value `@ tok[0] = .DATA` its returning false.....have checked the `tok[]` array to the data is getting assigned correctly.....
but 
condition it still gives false.....

```
OUTPUT :

     temp is .DATA
         SS IS .DATA
         tok[num] .DATA
         toknum 0
     temp is DATAENDS
         SS IS DATAENDS
         tok[num] DATAENDS
         toknum 1tok[0] is .DATA
    r is : false
```

Comment: Maybe you have trailing spaces?

Comment: try `tok[0].trim().equalsIgnoreCase(".DATA")`. It might have leading/trailing spaces. I'm pretty sure that equalsIgnoreCase() is right that the strings are not equals ;)

Comment: paste output of this line: System.out.print("tok[0] is "+tok[0]);

Comment: @ImranTariq better this: `System.out.print("tok[0] is '" + tok[0] + "'");`

Comment: Pablo .....when i'm using a string it work correct......

Comment: Sure Hiery shall let know .... :)...... Imran i have been using the same since long time(old habbits...)

Comment: THANKS A LOT Hiery Nomus.....it wrks now problem was with white spaces i guess.... n thank u all for ur response

Comment: We need to give the condition as

    if(tok[0].trim().equalsIgnoreCase(".DATA")) 
     {
         ...........
         ............
      }

as tok[0] may contain white spaces and in comparison even a space can bring in error.....

so, its advice able to use .trim() .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you find [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) or [`equalsIgnoreCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) is returning `false` when it should has return `true`. use [`trim`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) to rescue.

```
if(tok[0] != null && tok[0].trim().equalsIgnoreCase(".DATA"))
```

Comment: That ,my friends, is the experience talking :)